# Put call symmetry of put

Tags: options

I hope this is a simple question but I just wanted to get confirmation and also the intuition behind it.

I know the put call symmetry and I often see it expressed as:
Call(S, K) = Put(K, S) = K/S Put(S, S^2/K)
where S is the spot and K is the strike.

I was wondering if it is the same from the perspective of Puts, i.e.:
Put(S, K) = Call(K, S) = K/S Call(S, S^2/K)

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Just mechanically interchanging S and K in the first part I get that Call(K,S) = Put(S,K) = S/K Put(K,K^2/S) The last term could be rewritten as S/K Call(K^2/S, K)